# How to get (meteor) spiderable working with script tags

Tags: meteor, typekit

I've been trying to implement the spiderable package today, and wasn't able to get it working for awhile because I was seeing this error when I went to http://localhost:3000/?escaped_fragment=

```
Meteor code must always run within a Fiber.
```

After lots of debugging I got it to work when I removed all of the `<script>` tags in my `<head>`. The issue is that I need those tags in order to load services for my site like typekit, zopim, google analytics, etc.

How can I get spiderable to work and keep my script tags?

Comment: If the   <scripts> Tags are the problem why dont just download the .js files and put then on the /lib folder?

Comment: This error `Meteor code must always run within a Fiber.` is a server side error & shouldn't happen client side. It's possible something else is causing it not the script tags. If you have callbacks from npm modules ensure that you use `Meteor.bindEnvironment` to make the error go away

Comment: @Ethaan I can't put them in /lib because they need to access the `window` object and the `document` object. Even if i put the scripts in the compatibility folder, I get the same fiber error. The only thing that works for spiderable is removing all of them.

Comment: @Akshat even if I remove ALL my server side logic I still see the same error. Even created a fresh project and saw the error as soon as i added my `<script>` tags, so I think they are triggering the error in some capacity.

Comment: Ok now I've narrowed it down to one library that causes this bug — typekit. Any idea how I can modify typekit so that it isn't causing this bug?

Comment: @gaplus I don't think its an issue with Meteor if removing typekit fixes it. Make sure your phantomjs installation supports typekit (it requires a special version & special libraries). I'm not sure where the error comes from, are you using the normal spiderable package or another one? Do you have any npm module in your project

Comment: @Akshat what do you mean it requires a special version & special libraries? What libs are you referring to?

Comment: @gaplus The issue isn't that clear cut. You need certain libraries/development headers to build a phantomjs that supports webfonts. I'd recommend you check the github issues up on it as I'm not well versed on the details. I'm not absolutely certain it will fix your issue, as I mentioned the error is caused by a server side issue, from unofficial spiderable package or an npm module. If you could provide the details it may also solve your issue.

Comment: @gaplus Could you try running a phantomjs script against your server see (PhantomJS errors processing the page) over at http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/

Comment: @Akshat I tried running that script but all i got was this error :
`"URL file://phantomtest.js. Domains, protocols and ports must match."`

Comment: @gaplus I hope you're running the script with `phantomjs phantomtest.js` & have edited the meteorpedia.com to your localhost url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71035/discussion-between-gaplus-and-akshat).